# ViewPager doesn't always refresh when setAdapter is called, FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

First of all, I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to feed a ViewPager with fragments to display.

When app is in the running state (i.e. after `onResume()`), calling setAdapter on the ViewPager will always work and make my ViewPager refresh, the `getItem(int position)` method in the adapter is called.

However after an orientation change, if I call setAdapter in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` method of my activity, the `getItem(int position)` method is not called, and the old fragment is reused.

I am thinking maybe the FragmentManager is doing something that I don't understand? The Fragment Manager is the only thing that doesn't get destroyed during the orientation change.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the SavedState. I have the same problem but no solution. You can try following: befor you set the adapter call adapter.saveState, than set the adapter and call restoreSavedState with the saved state. In my case it didn't help, but maybe for you. Reason: in the ViewPager setAdapter it saved the current state and reused it. (i think)

Comment: Find the right answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910826/viewpager-fragmentstatepageradapter-orientation-change

Comment: Does this cause memory leaks ? Many say it does. Any other solution how to handle this scenario ?

Comment: yes! look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910826/viewpager-fragmentstatepageradapter-orientation-change

Comment: awesome, thanks for the reply. finally solved it..

Comment: @Informatic0re thanks man. That was right answer!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It could be because you are using `getFragmentManager()` to instantiate the FragmentStatePagerAdapter while using nested fragments.

Try using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead:

```
CustomFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588907/2153244).

Comment: Thanks save my times..!

Answer (score 1):

Well here is the thing that I found out (it's very very odd).

If you need to **refresh** items in `PagerAdapter` you will most certainly fail to do so creating new instances of `PageAdapter` when you do pass the same `FragmentManager` and passing them to the `setAdapter` call of `ViewPager`, e.g.:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(fm));
```

or

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(fm));
```

But if you'll constantly switch `FragmentManager`s when you're initialising `PagerAdapter` then it'll work.

From my point of view it's horrible... If anyone has ideas of how to refresh items in `ViewPager` properly (and not in this dirty way), share your thoughts with others :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the FragmentPagerAdapter and mViewPager.setAdapter() is not work.I fix it in the below step:
(1)get the current Fragment list.

```
List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
List<Fragment> fragmentListCopy = new ArrayList<Fragment>(fragmentList);
```

(2)remove fragment mamually

```
//I have two fragment
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentList.get(0)).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentList.get(1)).commit();
```

(3)set new FragmentPagerAdapter to ViewPager

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(...)
```

Just remove the fragments before you set new Adapter.