# ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter + orientation change

Tags: android, caching, android-viewpager, adapter, fragment

I have a little Problem: i have a ViewPager with some Pages and i use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter to handle the data. In portrait i have for example 20 pages for the ViewPager and in landscape i have just 10 pages for the ViewPager. So on a orientation change i create a new Adapter with different Data.

Here a little explanation why: I show one image in portrait and two in landscape but always all in count. If i have 10 pictures to show, i have 10 in portrait and 5 in landscape (always two).

But now i have a strange bug:
When i am in Landscape on index 5 and turn the device, the ViewPager's current page is set to 10. If i turn it back again i am on page 5. If i swipe the ViewPage now to page 10 the methode getItem of the adapter is never called and the ViewPage shows me the one portrait picture and not the two for landscape. 
How can this happen? Is there a cache in the adapter or ViewPager? In the onCreate of the Activity everything is new created, the adapter and also the data (just strings with path) for the ViewPager. 
So any idea how to fix this really scary "feature"?

Here are some code:

onCreate:

```
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ReaderPageViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getBaseContext(), mCurrentDocument.mPages, getResources()
                .getConfiguration().orientation);
    mPageReader = (ReaderViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPageReader.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
```

adapter getItem:

```
    public Fragment getItem(final int index) {
        final PageInfo pageInfo = mPages.get(index);
        final PageFragment pageFragment = (PageFragment) PageFragment
                .instantiate(mContext, pageInfo.mClss.getName(), pageInfo.mArgs);
        return pageFragment;
    }
```

If you need something more just tell me. Thanks

Comment: For me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629463/fragmentpageradapter-how-to-handle-orientation-changes approach fit perfectly!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can override the FragmentActivity onSaveInstanceState() and not call the super.onSaveInstanceState() in the method.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**Do not use** `mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);`

it ended up with a big memoryLeak. After every change of the orientation it puts the Fragments into an array of FragmentManager and never cleaned it. So it goes up to over 100mb memory usage after change the orientation many times. Using the onSaveInstanceState method is a better way I think.

Comment: I have to verify that setSaveEnabled has caused me 6hours of memory leak debugging.

Comment: Sorry to ask so late but did you ever find out what in super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) was causing this unexpected behavior ? Thanks in advance ! ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is late :-) in onSaveInstanceState it saved the fragments in an Array, which is never cleaned. Without calling super, it doesn't save the fragments in this arrays.

Comment: @Informatic0re I have view pager state problem but not the same condition. My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20310922/1156041). I did as ur answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: Solved my problem, too. For my situation this is one of the most useful information here on SO. Thank you so much!

Comment: In my case, I avoid calling to Fragment setInitialSavedState()

Answer (score 2):

I also occurred this problem and I found the reason.

Ever screen rotated, The `FragmentManager` will retain all your activity hosted fragments, It wou't remove fragments If using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, You can use `FragmentManager.getFragments()` to check the number of fragments.

Example: The activity has 4 fragments, After 4 times orientation change, The list `FragmentManager.getFragments()` size will be **20**!

I found some solutions:

1. Do not call the `super.onSaveInstanceState()` of you Activity, But It's seems not a good solution, Fragments can't save state and restore.
2. Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
   But after orientation changed, The fragments which `ViewPager` hosted was blanked(Does anyone else has same problem?). But I can remove all fragments in `Activity.onCreate` to fix it. like this:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
       List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
       if (fragments != null) {
           FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
           for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
               transaction.detach(fragment).remove(fragment);
           }
           transaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
       }
       ...
   ```

   But the `Fragment.onCreateView()` called twice.

I'm still looking for the perfect solution :D

Edit:
I finally solved the problem, It's cause by my ViewPager is add after onStart. When run to onStart, The `FragmentManager` will try to restore fragments state. I traced into `FragmentManager`, Have these code:

[com/android/support/support-fragment/24.2.1/support-fragment-24.2.1-sources.jar!/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKpa4.jpg)

Check the highlight line, The `f.mContainerId` actually is my ViewPager  id. Then it will try to add fragments view to ViewPager, In my case, The ViewPager is not add yet, So it will be blanked, But fragments state are `ATTACHED`. And in `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem()`, If the fragment was added, It just do `attach` the fragment, But the fragment is already attached, So its do nothing :(

I add ViewPager to activity layout XML, its fixed.

Happy coding :D

Answer (score -1):

Just you use in viewPager.setonpagechangelistener and implement for require code apply your application,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: i already implement the OnPageChangeListener but i don't want to do all the work there. I think there is just a cache or something i need to clear. Maybe of the ViewPager or FragmentManager. The adapter is completely new created, the ViewPage is recreated with findViewById, so why does something save a cache? Maybe it is the savedState but i dont know how to delete it.