# Android view pager is not load the web view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have main activity which has three fragments. I want to switch these fragments like this (**Fragment1 <-> Fragment2 <-> Fragment3**). In Fragment2, I used the `ViewPager` which has fragments embedded with `WebView`. I used `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

I used `popBackStack` method.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
```

My problem is that when I get back from the Fragment3, the Fragment2 show blank page. In my opnion, `ViewPager` cannot load the `Fragment` with `WebView`. I cann't find the solution. any idea pls?

Thanks

Comment: I guess this is a "problem" of the WebView and loading its data instead of a ViewPager problem. Maybe you have to reload the data of the WebViews

Comment: @Informatic0re when I debug this fragment, it didn't call `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` `getItem` method after come back from the `Fragment3`. so I don't have chance to reload the webview.

Comment: the is because of the fragment is not destroyed, so it exist already, there is no need to load it again. If you open Fragment1, Fragment2 will be loaded as well. Try to implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, on OnPageSelected you can reload it

Comment: @Informatic0re I am sorry for late reply. I used `mPager.setSaveEnabled(false)`. It work. But it takes a little time to load the fragment in view pager. I am worry about the memory leak as u said. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the DDMS to check if your memory will grow on every rotation.

Comment: I found another way. I extends the `PagerAdapter` and override the `instantiateItem()` method. Every `instantiateItem` method call, I add new fragment into the fragment transaction. like this   `fragment = getItem(position);`
`mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, .. );`. I would like to know ur opnion. Do u think they are the same result on memory? Thank again.