# ViewPager FragmentStatePagerAdapter keep more than three fragments in memory

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

The problem is ive got sort of book reader, landscape shows two pages and portrait just one. For some reason I blocked destroying activities on config change. the story is pretty much the same like here [ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter + orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13910826/1297987). Although the question is bit different - Id wish to store not 3 but 5 fragments. its about rendering time, Im easily handling swipe stuffs with adding +-1 in portrait and +-2 in landscape, though the problem is, in landscape orientation, it wont render proper next / previous fragments. As obviously its rendering +1 and -1 items, I want +2/-2 items to be instantiated instead. So theres either some kind of solution that changes positions to instantiate in landscape (which im not aware of though), or storing 5 items in an adapter instead of just 3.
Anyone with any sort of proper solution?

Answer (score 12):

You can store 5 items in the adapter by setting the OffscreenPageLimit  of the ViewPager to 4:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

hope that I've helped you.

Comment: thanks, though the performance dropped badly, what about rendering just +-2 element instead of  +-1?

Answer (score 2):

try this:
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

Comment: thanks, though the performance dropped badly, what about rendering just +-2 element instead of  +-1?