# trouble displaying fragments instance number

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

I've been following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html
 on how to use fragmentstatepageradapters.
It works well but I can't seem to be able to use the ArrayListFragment's instance number.
In the tutorial there is this bit displaying the instance number as a header:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
...
```

When I start the app the first screen show Fragment 0. when I swipe to the  next screen it shows Fragment 1 and so forth.
But when I add this:

`Log.i("instancenumber", Integer.toString(mNum));`

right below `((TextView)tv)...` the log shows

`instancenumber 0`

`instancenumber 1`

right when I start the app before I even touched anything and when I swipe right it switches to 2 and when I swipe to the last one it doesn't log anything and going backwards somehow also doesn't update correctly.

I'm guessing I'm not understanding either the concept of instance numbers or the onCreateView method correctly.
How can I get the correct instance number? It seems to work with the textview.

thanks in advance,

hachel

PS: context: I need the number because I have an mp3 playing and I want it to play faster (playback speed calculated by increasing instance number) and I also display a new image when I swipe to the next screen

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` always create the current view and the next one, so it will call the `onCreateView` from to the first and the next even when just showing the first one.

It does this to improve performance, when you scroll to the next view, the view is already created and Android can show it right way. When you scroll to the second view, the `onCreateView` of the third view will be called.

You can set how much fragments the `PagerAdapter` will keep in memory with `setOffscreenPageLimit`, there are more info in this question: [ViewPager FragmentStatePagerAdapter keep more than three fragments in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469011/viewpager-fragmentstatepageradapter-keep-more-than-three-fragments-in-memory)

Comment: ok, I could disable/set to zero caching of fragments, i'll look into that. Is there another way to dynamically see on which fragment I currently am?

Comment: @hachel You should not disable it, it will create a lag when you change the selected fragment. To get the current fragment, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I can't be using oncreateview for that then because of the caching but rather use some listener for that?

Comment: I made it work like below.
I now have a new problem with my mediaplayer in combination with currentItem but I'll post that in another question.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

with the help of jonathanrz I managed to make it work like this:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i("int", Integer.toString(mPager.getCurrentItem()));
            }
        });
```

Comment: You just needed the index of the position? I thought that you need some more custom data.

Comment: this is what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944680/play-different-looping-sound-each-time-i-swipe-to-a-new-fragment