# Fragments in ViewPager turns empty/blank when opening+returning from other fragment + orientation etc

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am trying to construct an application where you can scroll through objects with a ViewPager. The ViewPager holds Fragments, support library due to SDK 9 restriction. The fragments are constructed from data in a bean-object.

When I leave the active view (with a transaction.replace) to another fragment (and returns) the page I'm on and 1-2 to the left and the right becomes blank- nothing from the xml is shown and the background of the ViewPager-xml-element is shown. When scrolling x pages the content returns to the pages (not all of them, you need to scroll around more for that). When I enter and leave a PreferenceActivity, I do not get this error.

What is causing this behaviour and how can I fix it?

My app looks like this:

1 FragmentActivity that has a FrameLayout. 2 fragments that replaces each other when called. Inside one of the fragments, browser, is some buttons and a ViewPager. The ViewPager has a (Fixed [1](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/))FragmentStateChangeAdapter. If this is changed to FragmentChangeAdapter there is no difference.

The activity has a list of beans used in the ViewPager and a ListView in the other fragment, Search.

I've tried some suggestions without result:

[ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter + orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910826/viewpager-fragmentstatepageradapter-orientation-change)

[A bug in (and a fix for) the way FragmentStatePagerAdapter handles fragment restoration](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/)

I can supply code but this feels like a theory question, maybe in regard to saved states etc.

Comment: can you share the code for creating the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

To create CustomPagerAdapter please extend the FragmentStatePagerAdapter .

You can follow this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

I was having same problem and it works for me.

If you are still having this problem then please let me know.

Comment: As I said I need to have support for SDK9, does not v13 mean that it supports a minimum of SDK13?
I don't have the problem anymore since I did a work-around using activities. Not as flexible but suiting to the SDK

Answer (score 0):

**Query: When You change fragment You call web service.
you can use that code in manifest try it.**

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this or how it will help? It has nothing to do with the falsely saved savedstates of a FragmentStatePagerAdaptor. It might solve something for orientation or screenSize changes if I'm guessing correctly- but standard usage would still be the same.