# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem is not being triggered

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Currently, with a `FragmentActivity`, I toggle among 2 type of Fragments using the following code.

```
private void toggle() {
    Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (oldFragment instanceof ColorFragment) {
        fragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
    } else {
        fragment = new ColorFragment(android.R.color.black);
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

2 Fragments are being toggle.

- **ColorFragment** - A simple fragment which fill up its background with solid black color.
- **ViewPagerFragment** - A fragment contains `ViewPager`. User can swipe between a purple color fragment, and a blue color fragment.

The code which responsible for swiping purple and blue color fragments are as below.

```
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new ColorFragment(android.R.color.holo_purple);
        default:
            return new ColorFragment(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
        }
    }      
}
```

However, I encounter the weird behavior during toggling.

1. Black color fragment was shown.
2. Toggling.
3. View pager, which can swipe between purple and blue fragments shown.
4. Toggling.
5. Black color fragment was shown.
6. Toggling.
7. **Nothing shown, as MyFragmentPagerAdapter's getItem is not being triggered.**

I think my situation is similar to [FragmentPagerAdapter getItem is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581896/fragmentpageradapter-getitem-is-not-called)

However, I prefer not to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, because of *the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.*

Any workaround to overcome this problem?

I include a complete workable source code to demonstrate this problem : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jok9tz5ktvfcteo/viewpagerbug.zip

Comment: *I prefer not to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter* - well, did you at least tried it to see if it makes any differences? *because of the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.* - what potentially overhead? the scenario you posted with two fragments is dead simple.

Comment: @Luksprog The 2 purple and blue color fragments are for demonstration purpose. The real cases fragments are more complicated than that. I know I can reduce certain extend of overhead, by saving the information through bundle, or retained instance fragment technique. however, i realize the best way to avoid overhead for my case, is to avoid using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> Any workaround to overcome this problem?

I've downloaded your code and the problem appears because you don't handle those `Fragments` right. Most precisely you use nested `Fragments` in the `ViewPager` based `Fragment` and for that `ViewPager` you create the adapter like this:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
```

Instead, you should be using `getChildFragmentManager()` to bind the nested fragments:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
```

Also, you shouldn't pass data through a constructor to a `Fragment` as that data will not survive a configuration change and bad things will start to appear. Use a `Bundle` instead.

Comment: Hey. Really thanks for big help. However, I do not understand why using this.getChildFragmentManager will solve the problem. As from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html, it is using FragmentActivity's fragment manager through getSupportFragmentManager() (FragmentActivity is the owner of ViewPager). It does not use ArrayListFragment's fragment manager (ArrayListFragment(s) are the swipable contents of ViewPager)

Comment: In this.getChildFragmentManager(), it is returning the fragment manager for purple and blue fragments. This is different from the official example, which is using ViewPager's owner's fragment manager. Hence, this confuses me some how.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really answers my own question. I think the example given is fragment within activity. Using getFragmentManager makes sense. However, if for nested fragment within fragment, using getChildFragmentManager is needed. This is some how a "rule" posted by Google : http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: @CheokYanCheng `getFragmentManager()` in your `ViewPagerFragment` example will return the `FragmentManager` from the `Activity`(it's basically the value of `getSupportFragmentmanager()` in the `FragmentActivity` used to add the `Fragment`). As you use nested fragments those require the `getChildFragmentManager()` so they can be attached to the parent fragment. `getFragmentManager()` and `getChildFragmentManager` **aren't** the same thing in a `Fragment`(one returns the fragment related to the fragment and the other is the fragmentmanager used for its nested fragments).

Comment: If I could +1 more then once I would! Thanks so much for both the answer and the explanation!

Comment: works perfectly! i've had the same problem using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager doesn't exist in the support packages though?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns getChildFragmentManager is available for support fragments: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Strange part is that the `getItem(int pos)` still not getting called but the viewpager is showing fragments perfectly! Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

**Global working tested solution.**

`getSupportFragmentManager()` keeps the null reference some times and View pager does not create new fragment instance.Since it finds reference to same fragment. So to over come this use `getChildFragmentManager()` solves problem in simple way.

**Don't**

**`new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);`**

**Do**

**`new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() , fragments);`**

Answer (score 2):

Simple use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

or

you can use `new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager())`

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was correctly calling

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
```

but then in the nested fragment I was trying to replace the container fragment with another one by using:

```
getFragmentManager()
```

You need to go to the activity and call

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my cases it worked after add this to my **FragmentPagerAdapter**:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

and I also used **getChildFragmentManager()** like Luksprog said