# Viewpager in fragment not getting updated when navigating back to fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Below is the code of my ViewpagerAdapter

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, arg0 );
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int returnVal=0;
        if (totalPlayer%5==0) {
            returnVal= totalPlayer/5;
        }
        else
        {
            moduloImage=totalPlayer%5;
            returnVal= (totalPlayer/5)+1;
        }   
        return returnVal;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

When i load my fragment first time, it displays all items in view pager. Then when i navigate to new fragment by adding this fragment into stack, It shows next screen. After that when i pop previous fragment which conatins viewpager from stack on button back press, It displays all values as i had set before and also shows viewpager indicator to the exact position at which i had left but view pager items seems to be shown invisible. When i scroll viewpager, it is updated and shows perfect.

I have tried by updating viewpager but it seems to be doing nothing.

I have intialized view pager as,

```
pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager()));
pager.setCurrentItem(0);
indicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

Comment: have you tried to refresh the values inside  ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried by refreshing the whole value array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Issue was in initialisation of my viewPager.

I need to initiate it by,

```
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager()));
```

instead of

```
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager()));
```

I had refered [FragmentPagerAdapter getItem is not being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588120/fragmentpageradapter-getitem-is-not-being-triggered) accepted answer.

Hope it might help someone who is facing the same issue.